# Spark Java dataframe - Size of partition

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, partition

I have a dataframe with 1600 partitions.

1. How can I get the size(in mb) of each partition?
2. How can I get the total size(in mb) of the dataframe? Would it be correct if I persist it and check the Storage tab of SparkUI?

Comment: Do you want to get such informations at runtime in code or just to get familiar with your data after some test run?

Comment: Thank you very for your answer! I would like to print it at runtime in the console or stdout of each node.

Comment: I  used below command in the code: sp.sessionState().executePlan(df.queryExecution().logical()).optimizedPlan().stats().sizeInBytes() but it gives me a way to big number: 9223372036854775807 and if I divide that by 1600 partitions it still is a huge number.

Comment: Maybe your dataset was not cached? I added my answer with more details, i know it does not fully answer your question but maybe it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if there is an easy way to get exact size in byte for partition in runtime, but if you want to know this to find skew you can easily get number of records for each partition with something like this (its Scala)

```
df.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(it.size)).show
```

If your dataset is cached you get get size in bytes in your codes from statistics. Please remember, that your dataset needs to be cached and there needs to be some action between caching and reading from statistics. If you need sample action you can use something like this: input.cache.foreach(_ => ())

```
val bytes = spark
    .sessionState
    .executePlan(repartitioned.queryExecution.logical)
    .optimizedPlan
    .stats
    .sizeInBytes
```

Same work when you load your data from file, for example csv or json (in this case Spark is creating statistics "for free" during load) or when you are reading from input with compatible and accurate statistics (for example Hive table)

Other options are available via SparkUI. First is as you mentioned just to cache te dataset and get the size from storage tab. Other options is to check input or shuffle write/read sizes during stage which is interesting for you. It can show you if you have some skew

[image]

Here you can see a very clear example, this is a list of tasks (1 task = 1 partition) for stage on which i did foreach(_ => ()) on my dataset, it shows pretty well how data are organised within partitions, you can both size and number of records.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well actually it is a bit more complicated, I am repartitioning an RDD according to Cassandra Replicas in 1600 partitions and joining it with a Cassandra table and then transform it in a Dataframe. So basically one partition from Cassandra is in one partition in Spark, but one Spark partition may have more than one Cassandra partitions. After measuring times, I saw that for 1600 partitions it has the best time and I am trying to find why. Yes my data has skew as ti seems that some tasks have input size 120KB and other 250MB, but it depends on how much data I pull from Cassandra.